# Update statement in MYSQL from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

I have a table as shown below
[image]

The output from said table [image]
Green, is where a winner has been announced, whereas yellow means they have submitted a report, but a winner hasn't been decided yet. (winner field not populated)

```
        $roundBound = Array();
        $query = "SELECT MIN(id), MAX(id) FROM $tablename GROUP BY round";
        if($result = $Login->mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                $roundBound[] = $row[0];
                $roundBound[] = $row[1];
            }
        }
        for($i = 0; $i < count($roundBound); $i = $i + 2) {
            $match = 0;
            for($j = $roundBound[$i]; $j < $roundBound[$i + 1]; $j = $j + 2) {
                $id1 = $j;
                $id2 = $j+1;
                $query = "SELECT t1.winner, t2.winner FROM $tablename as t1, $tablename as t2 WHERE t1.id=$id1 AND t2.id=$id2";
                $result = $Login->mysqli->query($query);
                $row = $result->fetch_row();
                $win1 = $row[0];
                $win2 = $row[1];
                if (isset($win1) && isset($win2)) {
                    if (isset($roundBound[$i + 2])) {
                        $id = $roundBound[$i + 2] + $match;
                        $query = "UPDATE $tablename SET
                            username = '$win1',
                            username2 = '$win2'
                            WHERE id = $id";
                        $Login->mysqli->query($query);
                    } else {
                        //Tourneydonneee yeeee
                    }
                }
                $match++;
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have a improvement, or an all-around different idea? This will be running quite often and could be potentially running on large record sets, so optimization would also be welcome.

Comment: how 2 user name can be inserted on same row??

Comment: One field is called username, another is called username2. This portion is complete, what I am doing now is moving the field winner from two rows, into the username fields for the next round.

Comment: wat about `wasd`; he is also winner from round 1. and what is the importance of report 2 column?

Comment: @diEcho Pretty much a user reports their win, or loss. If the other opponent has not reported a win or loss by 5 minutes, the other is assumed the winner regardless which is what lastReport is used for. wasd would not be advanced into round 2 yet because his potential opponent herpderp69 or wzee doesn't have a winner announced.

Comment: This goes off topic, but might be of use, if both users report win, the match is locked, and is pending an admin review to settle the dispute.

Comment: @diEcho This may help you understand, at the bottom of the page is the output..

http://www.sjscomputing.com/dailies/dailies/brackets/?game=Starcraft2

If a definite winner has been announced, their name is colored in green, whereas if it is pending (waiting for the 5 minutes to be over...) it is yellowish. I will also add this to my question.

Comment: @genesis, freehand circles ftw. I thought the "visual aid" might connect the two in peoples mind :P Thanks for the laugh when I saw it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i understand you problem, i can suggest you to try

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i = $i + 2) {
    $win1 = mysql_query("SELECT winner FROM tableName WHERE id=".(int)$i);
    $win2 = mysql_query("SELECT winner FROM tableName WHERE id=".(int)$i+1);
    $qry = "INSERT INTO tableName SET 
                          username = $win1,
                          username2 =$win2,
                          ....";
    mysql_query($qry);
}
```

Comment: I am just looking for a more comprehensive answer to my question, well these queries will work individually, it doesn't make any attempt to answer any question of optimization.

Comment: I'll vote this up for now, and I can see myself accepting it. If anyone can provide answers to optimization I would appreciate it.